# Maintaining login state on refresh using cookies in Angular 4 + ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I started out by tracking my login status using an `isLoggedIn` flag in the Authentication Service I wrote, it is set to `true` when the user successfully authenticates on the backend with Identity.

Now I want a way to keep them logged in so they don't always have to login when refreshing the page. I added this function to my Authentication Service:

```
testLogin() : Observable<boolean> {
return this.httpClient.post("/api/Account/TestLogin", null, { observe: "response" })
  .map(result => {
    if (result.ok) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }

    return this.isLoggedIn;
  });
}
```

And this to my backend (Controller is behind `[Authorize]` attribute):

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult TestLogin()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

I check this when my app starts, in `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
  authService.testLogin().subscribe(result => {});
}
```

The issue is my route guard `canActivate` returns `true` if the `isLoggedIn` flag is true, otherwise redirects to the login page and returns `false`. This happens before the `testLogin` function request is finished, so I get redirected to login even though I am successfully authenticated, I can navigate around the page from the login page without signing in. Is this the wrong way to do this? I'm just using the default ASP.NET Core Identity setup with cookies, but most guides I've found on this use JWT which I am not using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a service to hold your isLoggedIn status.

. On app start set loginService.isLoggedIn = false;

. On Login Component and if login is OK set loginService.isLoggedIn = true;

then use router to navigate router.navigate(['home']);

. On authGuard check for loginService.isLoggedIn value.

You can also use a function in your service to set/get the isLoggedIn value ( which will be private to the service in that case )